# Multiple Y Values in Excel graph

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I have sensor readings that go back several months in column B, in excel. Column A has the timestamps of these readings...

For insance,

```
A    B
000  0    
030  -4
100  2
 ...
1130  3
0000  6
```

Over the course of many months...

I would like to create a graph in excel of column B vs column A, where the X axis only consists of 000, 030, 100, .... 1100, 1130 and the various Y values are every instance of the each X value in my data. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a standard scatter plot not do it for you?

[image]

Comment: for some reason I had kept doing line graphs. silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Do the values in column A correspond to times in hmm or hhmm format? Convert them to times in h:mm format, and if the times span multiple days, include the date as well (d/m/yy h:mm).

Plot the data on an XY chart (not a line chart). Use a custom number format of hmm for the X axis.